# Trouble Accessing Remote Postgres DB on Heroku from Local Node.js Webapp

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I struggled today to get my local node.js app to reach out to the db on Heroku instead of settling for a parallel db on my machine.  Thanks to a post I tested and then stopped expecting

```
process.env.DATABASE_URL
```

to provide the URL and replaced it with the actual URL from

```
heroku config
```

along the lines of

`var connectionString = "postgres://thinga:thingb@ec2-23-21-119-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/thingc";`.

But that didn't solve the problem completely.  I found I also had to use

```
var pg = require('pg').native;
```

to force SSL.  And in order to get that to work I had to rollback my pg module to

```
"pg": "2.x"
```

There must be a better way.  Anyone?

P.S. I also set

```
NODE_ENV: development
```

but I don't know if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You helped me fix the same problem on my machine, but I didn't have to go as far as you did.

I had already changed **process.env.DATABASE_URL** to **connectionString** after declaring:

**var connectionString = 'postgres://thinga:thingb@ec2-54-204-42-119.compute-1.amazonaws.com:thingc';**

Adding **.native** to **var pg = require('pg');** seems to have made the difference for me.

1. I did NOT need to change **pg** in the dependencies. I left it at **"pg": "4.x"**.
2. I did not use this: **NODE_ENV: development**.

But thank you so much for your help.