# pull data from heroku using postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting started with node.js using [this heroku walkthrough](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database). I've gone through to the end and now I want to pull the data from the remote database onto my local version.

I've just run `$ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[mycolor] mylocaldb --app [myappname]` as per the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) and that has returned a bunch of `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` messages.

```
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading event triggers
pg_dump: finding extension members
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "test_table"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = UTF8
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_dump: dumping contents of table test_table
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA public
pg_restore: creating COMMENT SCHEMA public
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: creating COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: creating TABLE test_table
pg_restore: processing data for table "test_table"
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for DATABASE dfm6qsm6f0l9kh
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for SCHEMA public
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for COMMENT SCHEMA public
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for TABLE test_table
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for TABLE DATA test_table
```

Now when I access the /db route I still get this error message:

```
Error error: relation "test_table" does not exist
```

What else do I need to do to properly pull this data down?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just acessing the remote Heroku Postgres db from my local app, which is, I think, as Heroku intends it, FWIW. But Heroku is not doing something correctly, I gather. I hacked my setup like this:

[Trouble Accessing Remote Postgres DB on Heroku from Local Node.js Webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263559/trouble-accessing-remote-postgres-db-on-heroku-from-local-node-js-webapp/27595531#27595531)

Given what other posts have indicated, I'm not sure it's the best long-term solution, but I have no problem with it.